# uiautomation iOS uilabel value

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to get the value from a UILabel by doing a `target.logElementTree()` but I am unable to see the value that the Label is actually set with.

It only shows the string that we set based on the accessibilityLabel

```
self.settlementDate.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
self.settlementDate.accessibilityLabel = @"DetailViewInCode_SettlementDate";
```

And in the `target.logElementTree()` this is the value that I see i the log of Instruments-Automation

```
UIAStaticText: name:DetailViewInCode_SettlementDate value:DetailViewInCode_SettlementDate rect:{{260, 345}, {304, 21}}    

UIALogger.logMessage("Target static:"+target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().staticTexts()["Activity_DetailedView_SettlementDate"].value());
```

And I can see the screenshot when I click on that entry
[image]

iOS 5.1 Simulator

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the value is set by **default** with the value of accessibilityLabel property. Try to set the accessibilityValue property in the code in the same manner you set the accessibilityLabel property.

```
self.settlementDate.accessibilityValue = <ActualVale>;
```

Comment: This is a really great piece of information. Setting both the accessibilityValue and accessibilityIdentifier of a UILabel provides a solution for something many people seem to look for but give up on: A way to easily get the value of a UILabel in a UIAutomation script, the way one would expect it to work: var foo = window.staticTexts()["myAccessibilityID"].value();

Answer (score -1):

The value is shown in the log. The value of that label is `DetailViewInCode_SettlementDate`.
The fact that the value and the name are identical might have been confusing you. This is not something uncommon.

Comment: Try using the `.label() ` attribute.